# Best way to store Terraform variable values without having them in source control

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform

We have a code repo with our IaC in Terraform.  This is in Github, and we're going to pull the code, build it, etc.  However, we don't want the values of our variables in Github itself.  So this may be a dumb question, but where do we store the values we need for our variables?  If my Terraform requires an Azure subscription id, where would I store the subscription id?  The vars files won't be in source control.  The goal is that we'll be pulling the code into an Azure Devops pipeline so the pipeline will have to know where to go to get the input variable values.  I hope that makes sense?

Comment: *However, we don't want the values of our variables in Github itself*. Why? Secrets aside, source control is *exactly* where you want to put variables.

Comment: Not the values.  You don't store passwords, certificates, those things in source control.  So I've no idea what you mean here.

Comment: I said *secrets aside*. The only example you provided, an Azure subscription ID, is a generic plaintext value that has no value being treated as a secret. Store plaintext, non-secret variable values in source control. Use a secret management system like Azure KeyVault for secure values.

Comment: No configuration setting should be in source control, that's what configuration management is for.  Our source code can stand up dozens of different environments, each with its own subscription id, different config values, different SKUs, number of load balancers, all of that.  A SKU may not be a secret, but should it should not be in source control.

Comment: I think you'll find that few agree with your stance. For non-secret infrastructure configuration values, source control is the *de facto* standard. There are even entire movements (i.e. GitOps) with associated toolchains that rely on source control as the primary driver of configuration.

Comment: This thread isn't helpful and at this point I'd like to respectfully cease the discourse.  Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

You can store your secrets in Azure Key Vault and retrieve them in Terraform using `azurerm_key_vault_secret`.

```
  data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "example" {
    name         = "secret-sauce"
    key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.existing.id
  }

  output "secret_value" {
    value = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.example.value
  }
```

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/key_vault_secret

Comment: That would work great for our values, but now the question is how to tell the pipeline which key vault I need.  So basically my Terraform would come down to just needing to know which key vault.  And I'd likely keep a different vault per environment as well, so it would have to be a variable.

Comment: If you have two environments Terraform will know which Key Vault to contacr as you will create one Key Vault per ENV. The code above will be valid for both ENV.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to go about setting this up, and I hate to be a pain.  When I set up two environments, I assume you're referring to Azure DevOps environments?

Comment: But there is a warning in the linked page saying `All arguments including the secret value will be stored in the raw state as plain-text.`. This means that we will just store in another place the same sensitive data

Comment: I'm still hazy on how Terraform knows which key vault to contact.  I do plan on a single key vault per environment, but how do I tell Terraform which environment?  I'd like to use a single pipeline as code but I don't want to bake this information in.  Is it possible to get a snippet of what pipeline as code would look like if I have say a production, staging, and development environment, each with their own key vault?

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a source of truth eventually.

You can store your values in the pipeline definitions as variables themselves and pass them into the Terraform configuration.

Usually it's a combination of tfvar files (dependent on target environment) and some variables from the pipeline. If you do have vars in your pipelines though, the pipelines should be in code.

If the variables are sensitive then you need to connect to a secret management tool to get those variables.

If you have many environments, say 20 environments and the infra is all the same with exception of a single ID you could have the same pipeline definition (normally JSON or YAML) and reference it for the 20 pipelines you build, each of those 20 would have that unique value baked in for use at execution. That var is passed through to Terraform as the missing piece.

There are other key-value property tracking systems out there but Git definitely works well for this purpose.

Comment: When the subject of  storing application or infrastructure configuration variables within the pipeline itself, I always like to raise this point: When you do that, you immediately eliminate the ability to easily debug locally and tightly couple your infrastructure deployment to a specific CI platform. Not a great situation. Meanwhile, if I have `dev.tfvars`, I can just do `terraform apply -var-file="dev.tfvars"` and I'm good to go.

Comment: @DanielMann, I agree with values being in the <env>.tfvars generally but the OP was requesting alternatives.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Azure DevOps Secure files (pipelines -> library) for storing your credentials for each environment. You can create a tfvar file for each environment with all your credentials, upload it as a secure file in Azure DevOps and then download it in the pipeline with a `DownloadSecureFile@1` task.